# Duplicate Css and Js render issue in next.js

Tags: html, css, duplicates

I am facing the duplicate css and js issue in next.js on page view-source.

first time it load the css and js with "preload" and seconds time it load with simple .

same with the CSS.

nextjs(9.2.1) with ssr,node (12.14.1),react(16.12.0)

[Please see the screenshot for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEinF.png)

Answer (score 1):

That is how preloading with the link tag works.

Please check out the MDN article on preloading: [Preloading With rel=preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)